# nginx proxy header with client socket port in addition to client IP

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to modify my nginx configuration so that I can pass through the origin client's IP as well as the client's socket source TCP port, as when I pass the connection to my upstream server it recognizes the source IP and port as being the one opened by nginx instead of the client, ie:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;                              │
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;          │
```

is there such a thing as $remote_port? I'm not sure if the only way to achieve this would be to write my own module?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The ngx_http_core_module module supports embedded variables with names matching the Apache Server variables. First of all, these are variables representing client request header fields, such as $http_user_agent, $http_cookie, and so on. Also there are other variables:

`$remote_port` - client port

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: Does not work in docker. I have an nginx running in a docker container. In my browser I request myurl.de:8091. §remote port is 40366? What could be wrong?

Comment: @user1383029 - 8091 is the server's listening port for the connection, the remote port is the port number the client uses at the other end of the connection.  If you inspect your current browser's connections (e.g. with netstat) you'll see most of the foreign addresses using (hopefully) port 443 (or https), but the local addresses will all use their own 'random' port numbers, typically in the higher range somewhere between 32768 - 65535.